# How to specify custom XCode location for calabash?

Tags: ios, calabash

If I run my application testing target with calabash from terminal with DEBUG=1 parameter I can see that calabash uses default Xcode location.

{
...
                 :xcode_path => "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
}

I'm wondering if there is any way to provide a custom location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to do that:

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer

{
...
                 :xcode_path => "/Applications/Xcode5.app/Contents/Developer"
}

If there is a better way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the location that calabash uses with the APP_BUNDLE_PATH parameter.

There are different ways to define that, here are 3 ways of doing it
1) Running calabash console
You need to define it like this

```
APP_BUNDLE_PATH=/<location> calabash-ios console
```

2) Executing your tests(non x-platform)
Define APP_BUNDLE_PATH in launch.rb

3) Executing you tests X-platform
Define APP_BUNDLE_PATH in the cucumber.yml file.

Comment: Lasse, I'm about XCode path, not app path.

Comment: But why do you need to change the xcode path? Perhaps I misunderstood, but the path to the app is needed to execute the tests and run the console so I thought that was what you were looking for.

Comment: I had an issue with latest xcode 6.1.1. Calabash was failing to execute touches on it. That's why I needed to specify other version of xcode (5.1.1) for that.